# Web Scraping using re:How to neglect html tags within the text we want to extract?

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping

I want to print the text between **`<p><span class="step_leadin"> and </p>`** in a html source code. I used the following code.

```
import urllib2
import re
url = ['http://recipes.latimes.com/recipe-restaurant-1833s-bacon-cheddar-biscuits-maple-chile-butter/']
htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://recipes.latimes.com/recipe-restaurant-1833s-bacon-cheddar-biscuits-maple-chile-butter/')
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex2 =  '<p><span class="step_leadin">(.+?)</p>'
pattern2 = re.compile(regex2)
method = re.findall(pattern2,htmltext)
print method
```

the part of the html i am trying to extract is.

```
<p><span class="step_leadin">Step1</span>Carefully transfer the biscuits to a rimmed baking sheet, spacing them an inch or so apart</p>
```

The problem is that when i use "print method" command it gives all the text  between those two tags including "`</span>`" also. But i dont want `</span>` to get printed in the output. Is there any way to neglect  tag while extracting the text i want.

Comment: Well, i did this and it worked!! `regex2='<p><span class="step_leadin">(.+?)</span>(.+?)</p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe heinst's answer is better, but since you insist on using regex, you can do something like this:

```
import re

html = '<p><span class="step_leadin">Step1</span>Carefully transfer the biscuits to a rimmed baking sheet, spacing them an inch or so apart</p>'

print re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', html)
```

Comment: Well, i did this and it worked too!! `regex2='<p><span class="step_leadin">(.+?)</span>(.+?)</p>`

Answer (score 1):

I strongly urge you not to use regex to parse html, because [html is not regular.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) Instead use an HTML/xml parser like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [lxml.](http://lxml.de/) Here is an example of what you are trying to do using BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<p><span class="step_leadin">Step1</span>Carefully transfer the biscuits to a rimmed baking sheet, spacing them an inch or so apart</p>'

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)

for p in bs.find_all('p'):
    print p.text
```

Comment: Thanks!!
I am new to web scraping. I already know about beautiful soup but i was trying to do the same problem using regex. I just want to explore this. Please share the answer using regex if possible.

Comment: I don't know regex too well, but what you could do is: `method = re.findall(pattern2,htmltext) method = method[0].replace('</span>', '') print method` I tried different combinations of regex for a solid 10 mins and couldn't get rid of the `</span>`

Comment: I still wonder if there was some command like .get_text to extract text. I used `text=i.get_text().split('/n')` in my beautiful soup code to do the same. Anyway, i will stick to beautiful soup...:) Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. If you think my answer was the most helpful, feel free to accept it as the correct answer.